# Balancing Attack to Defense in a text based RPG

Tags: rpg, php, mathematics

I understand that there is no correct or incorrect way of doing this, and its all down to a matter of trial and error in terms of perfecting the system.

What I am after is some advice or even get thoughts on how others have tackled a situation like this.

Right now I have a very basic attack formula

```
$attackPower = $baseAttack * 4; 
$percent = $attackPower / 100;
$percent1 = $percent * 10; // Gets 10% of the users attack power
```

Using the above code I then use rand to work out a users attack power, so it varies rather than a single number

```
$power = rand($attackPower - $percent1, $attackPower + $percent1)
```

So that's the users attack power calculated.

However if I used the same formula to calculate the opponents defense, and then calculated the Attack minus Defense equals the damage

```
$totalDamage = $power - $defense;
```

This may sometimes result in a negative value (especially if the opponent has a considerably higher defense stat to the users attack)

Above I have used

```
$attackPower = $baseAttack * 4;
```

For calculating the defense would this be efficient?

```
$defensePower = $baseDefense * 2; // Could have this set to rand? 1 - 3??
```

Is there anything that could be changed to balance the stats out a bit more? 
Could there be a much simpler formula?

Comment: Not an anwser, but quick coding advice: you're using a lot of bogus variables here. The top four lines could also be written: `$power = $baseAttack * rand(3.6, 4.4)`.

Comment: This [question/answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/how-to-develop-rpg-damage-formulas) also here on GameDev.SE might be interesting to read.

Comment: I have come across that already Philip, however right now I'm looking to keep it as simple as possible. Once users have started to build up their character, I may take a copy of their stats and play around with them locally to fine the system and/or try to find an alternative system through trial and error

Comment: Questions asking for "advice" or "thoughts" are generally too broad or discussion-based to be considered on-topic here. For now I closed this as a duplicate, but if you can sufficiently clarify the question it may be possible to reopen it. You can also consider asking in the [chat].

Answer (score 2):

### Handling negative values

There are ways to handle negative values aside from *healing* the high-defense enemy with your sword strike (which is weird).

You could introduce a **block** mechanic, where if `target defense > attack power`, the damage is nullified.

But this is imbalanced. This might mean you might encounter an opponent who you will never hit. Of course you don't want that.

### Rethinking defense

1. Your attack power *fluctuates*, which is understandable. Sometimes you get a good strike in (up to `10%` more damage), sometimes you don't (up to `10%` less). You could apply the the same mechanic to defense.
2. Instead of defense being **additive**, which might lead to an enemy never ever being damaged, you can make defense **multiplicative**. Instead of blocking of **N flat damage**, you can shave off **X% of the damage as a whole**. The increased complexity to this is that you either have to set a min and max defense reachable, up to a possible 99% damage reduction, or let defense scale from `1 to infinity` but as defense approaches infinity, the damage reduction increase should lessen.

Think of it like this graph :

[image: X = Defense, Y = Damage Reduction]

Where X = Defense and Y = Damage Reduction

Comment: I have considered a block mechanic, however it seems useless with the evasion system I have. Theoretically they are the same.

Comment: Yeah, block or evade or parry, technically the same thing in terms of results.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an IF statement:

```
IF ($power > $defence) {
 $totalDamage = $power - $defence;
} else {
 $totalDamage = 0;
}
```