# creating levelup stats based on curves

Tags: mathematics, python

I'm creating a simple level-up system and I'm looking to base the stats gain on curves so I can tweak them easier, I know it's a math function, but I have no idea what to search for.

---

I need to create this curve and get the value every x increment.

[image]

the engine I'm using is Ren'py and the language python. if you can tell me the terms to search for, I might be able to find something on the topic.

Comment: It looks like you want a function that offers diminishing returns, where the rate of increase slows the further you go. [There are many such functions you could use, with several covered in detail in existing answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109985/39518). Can you give those a try, and let us know if they solve your problem? If not, please edit your question to show us what you tried based on your research so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: I did a search for "ease out function" and found lots of results.

Comment: @DMGregory yes, that's exactly what I was searching for, thank you

Comment: No worries. I've closed this question as a duplicate for now. If you find those answers are not meeting your needs, please edit this question to explain what you've tried and what you want to change, and we can re-open it.